# Command Undead Contested Charisma

Tags: pathfinder-1e, mind-control

When rolling for contested charisma checks for multiple sources of control with command undead, how often can you contest the orders?

**Multiple Mental Control Effects**

> Sometimes magical effects that establish mental control render each other irrelevant, such as spells that remove the subject's ability to act. Mental controls that don't remove the recipient's ability to act usually do not interfere with each other. If a creature is under the mental control of two or more creatures, it tends to obey each to the best of its ability, and to the extent of the control each effect allows. If the controlled creature receives conflicting orders simultaneously, the competing controllers must make opposed Charisma checks to determine which one the creature obeys.

This seems to state they are contested, but can you attempt this once per round? Once per order? Once per spell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The Charisma checks are rolled once, at the time that the orders are given.

Let's say Ed the Enchanter has cast *Dominate Person* on someone to make them his servant. Being a wizard who's busy doing arcane research, he commands them to do his laundry, which they will continue to do until told to stop. Later, his wife, Clara the Charmer, wants the dishes done, but being busy with her own arcane research, instructs the servant to do the dishes for her, unaware that they were already doing chores for her husband. Since the servant is *Dominated* it doesn't listen to her, and she casts her own *Dominate Person* on our poor servant, and then instructs the servant to do the dishes (again), but with magical compelling force behind it.

Since the servant can only do one task at a time, *that* is the point is when the opposed Charisma checks are rolled, right when the opposing orders are given. If the wife wins the contest, then the servant immediately stops doing the laundry, and proceeds to the kitchen to wash the dishes. Should the wife fail the contest, the servant continues to do the laundry. It's important to note, however, that the wife can continue to reissue the command until she wins the contest.

It's also important to note that you don't technically *know* that you're making an opposed charisma check when you issue the new order. If the wife succeeds the first try, she'll have no idea that the servant was already under the effects of *Dominate Person* from her husband or that she was even in a charisma contest, and her husband will have no idea that his order was overwritten. On the other hand, should she lose the first contest, being a high level wizard, she would probably be able to figure out that the servant is already under the effects of a control spell and would probably just mention it to her husband to have the servant do dishes once they're done with the laundry, rather than wasting her time reissuing the command until it takes.

Finally, as to how quickly orders may be given, some spells or features explicitly say what type of action is required to issue a command, while others don't. In order to prevent someone from spending their turn reissuing the same command until they win the charisma contest, it should be limited to once per round.

Comment: Just for clarity; is this what we might call a Plain Reading of the rules already in the Q, or does have rules on those details (not personally familiar with the system, but it wouldn't surprise me whether do or don't). It might be fruitful to explicitly (but cleanly) say, just so it's clear to readers what your basis is.